# How to check if a select value equals a certain option using jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate for a form. I need to add some functionality so an additional field is required if a specific option is selected from a select/drop-down menu.

Here's the example they provide on the jQuery website to require a certrain field if an option is checked in a checkbox (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     contact: {
       required: true,
       email: {
         depends: function(element) {
           return $("#contactform_email:checked")
         }
       }
     }
   }
})
```

Here's what I'm doing, but it returns an error. Basically, if Football is chosen as a Favorite Sport from a drop down, then position is a required field.

```
$form.validate( {
rules: {
    favoriteSport: {
        required: true
    },
    position: {
            depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#favoriteSport[value="football"]');
            }
    }
}
```

});

Comment: favoriteSport doesn't have an attribute of value.  but has child nodes that do. #favoriteSport > option[value=football]
you could try: $('#favoriteSport > option[value=football]:selected')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$('#favoriteSport > option[value=football]:selected')
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. Now, whenever I go to type in the input that appears, it returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined" when I click outside of the input box. I guess this is due to jQuery Validate trying to validate the "#position" field? Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the code i see here, i don't see why you would be getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.Net or some other language that ruins the IDs of your controls, and you're looking for a way to have specific text selected, you can do this:

```js
$('[id$=NormalControlID] :selected').text("SomeValue");
```